# bootstrap affix floats all the way to the left when scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div within a container that I would like to stay fixed on the right side of the screen. But when the user start to scrolls it just shifts all the way to the left. Thanks for any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/kbLak/

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

recent things:

```
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="explore_recentAlbums" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="20">
    <div class="ex_recentBar">
        <div class="ex_titleDetails">
            <span>recent stuff: </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>

                    <div class="well well-small" style="margin-bottom: 1px;">
                        <span>Recent</span>
                    </div>

                    <span class="NoDataFound">No Photo.</span>


                    <div class="smallalbumcover">
                        <div class="mosaic-blocksmall mofade">
                            <div class="mosaic-overlay">
                                <div class="details">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="#">xzxz</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mosaic-backdrop">
                                <img src=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-bottom: 1em; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;">
                        <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/pics"><span class="label label-info">View More</span></a>
                    </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

                    <div class="well well-small" style="margin-bottom: 1px;">
                        <span>Recent Video Albums</span>
                    </div>

                    <span class="NoDataFound">No Video.</span>

                    <div class="smallalbumcover">
                        <div class="mosaic-blocksmall mofade">
                            <div class="mosaic-overlay">
                                <div class="details">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="/">test</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mosaic-backdrop">
                                <img src="#"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-bottom: 1em; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;">
                        <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/vids"><span class="label label-info">View More</span></a>
                    </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

                    <div class="well well-small" style="margin-bottom: 1px;">
                        <span>Recent P</span>
                    </div>

                    <span class="NoDataFound">No.</span>

                    <div class="smallalbumcover">
                        <div class="mosaic-blocksmall mofade">
                            <div class="mosaic-overlay">
                                <div class="details">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="/">test</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mosaic-backdrop">
                                <img src=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-bottom: 1em; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;">
                        <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/aio"><span class="label label-info">View More</span></a>
                    </div>


            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

​

Comment: You want to keep it fixed and going down when the user scrolls or fixed as in "it's not meant to move at all"

Comment: Yes, just stay fixed to the right as you scroll. Take a look at the jsfiddle example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this to your css and it will stay to the right:

```
.explore_recentAlbums {
    right: 0;     
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. So I am assuming that bootstrap has a left 0 when it applies the affix class to the div, that's why it pulls all the way to the left of screen.

Comment: Also it still moves to the right as you scroll. How to keep it in that position.

Comment: If you want to keep it at the top and on the right you can override .affix on the .explore_recentAlbums class setting the position to static.

.explore_recentAlbums.affix {
    position: static;
}